# Binding a property with is not a dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to bind Position of media element to it model view. I know about that property not being a dependency property. So tried it this way, a code i found on the net

```
<MediaElement Source="{Binding CurrentClip.Path, Converter={StaticResource converter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Stretch="Uniform" local:MediaElementHelper.Postion="{Binding CurrentClip.Postion}"
```

MediaElementHelper

```
class MediaElementHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PostionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Position",
        typeof(bool), typeof(MediaElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, PostionPropertyChanged));

    private static void PostionPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var richEditControl = obj as MediaElement;

        if (richEditControl != null)
        {
            richEditControl.Position = (TimeSpan)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
    public static void SetPostion(UIElement element, TimeSpan value)
    {
        element.SetValue(PostionProperty, value);
    }
    public static TimeSpan GetPostion(UIElement element)
    {
        return (TimeSpan)element.GetValue(PostionProperty);
    }
}
```

[Error]
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SetPostion' property of type 'MediaElement'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that you have wrong accessors names for your `AttachedProperty`.

Instead of `GetPostion` and `SetPostion` they should be `GetPosition` and `SetPosition` and offcourse similarly while using the AttachedProperty it should be `local:MediaElementHelper.Position` (not Postion).

Also you will need to update your `Type` and `default value` as suggested by other answers. But there is no need to derive your class from `DependancyObject`, rather you can make your class `static`.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong I can see is your Attached Property is not registered to the right type.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PostionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Position",
    typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(MediaElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSecond(0), ChangeHandler));
```

Figured I should put up a template for Attached Properties....

```
public class AttachedPropertyClass 
{
    private static readonly {PropertyType} DefaultValue = ...;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty {PropertyName}Property
       = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("{PropertyName}",
    typeof({PropertyType}), typeof({AttachedType}),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DefaultValue, PostionPropertyChanged));;

    public static void Set{PropertyName}(DependencyObject d, {PropertyType} value)
    {
        d.SetValue({PropertyName}, value);
    }

    public static {PropertyType} Get{PropertyName}(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return ({PropertyType})DepObject.GetValue({PropertyName});
    }

    private static void ChangeHandler(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e);
}
```

Comment: i get a new error Default value type does not match type of property 'Position

Comment: whoops....and you would be right...two places where you got the type wrong, the return type (explicit) and the default (false, implicitly was still bool). I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<MediaElement Source="{Binding CurrentClip.Path, Converter={StaticResource converter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Stretch="Uniform" local:MediaElementHelper.Position ="{Binding CurrentClip.Postion}">
```

Changes Made

```
public static class MediaElementHelper 
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan DefaultValue = new TimeSpan(0);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Position",
        typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(MediaElementHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DefaultValue, PositionPropertyChanged));

    private static void PositionPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var richEditControl = obj as MediaElement;

        if (richEditControl != null)
        {
            richEditControl.Position = (TimeSpan)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
    public static void SetPosition(UIElement element, TimeSpan value)
    {
        element.SetValue(PositionProperty, value);
    }

    public static TimeSpan GetPosition(UIElement element)
    {
        return (TimeSpan)element.GetValue(PositionProperty);
    }
}
```